# Self-oscillation in a commercial RF amplifier

Tags: amplifier, rf, stability, oscillation

I purchased several 50 ohm (in/out), 35 dB gain photomultiplier tube (PMT) amplifiers from a vendor assuming I could use them to read out the voltages on my PMTs.  The amplifiers are AC coupled with a 2k pull down resistor before the coupler.  To avoid RF interference (these PMTs are very sensitive to FM radio stations), I placed a metal box around the PMT and connected the amp via 50 ohm SMA cable through the box.  This gave me a relatively good output with only a moderate amount of 100MHz FM, so I designed a larger box for both the PMT and amplifier thinking I could shield both at once as well as cut down on cable losses.

However, when placed in the box with the PMT, the amplifier oscillates at its maximum output voltage at almost exactly its -3dB frequency (~ 1.6 GHz).  Outside the box (but with identical cabling length, power supply and load), but the PMT inside the box, its stable.  Outside the box, using an extra meter of RG58 cabling (higher source capacitance), its still stable.  If both are outside of the box however, its unstable.  This happens even when the PMT is unpowered.  I swapped amplifiers/PMTs and observed no difference.

I'm not an expert in RF, but I'm assuming this is some kind of parasitic coupling between the amplifier input and output, but I don't understand why putting a box around the the PMT prevents this.   I'm also a little surprise that the amps have so much trouble with the PMT (~20 pf, 100 MOhm).

Am I doing something foolish?

Comment: Compare the size of the larger box with the wavelength of 1.6 GHz. Have you built a resonant cavity?

Comment: The box is 0.5 x 0.2 x .85 wavelengths so thats a reasonable possibility, although its rather full of components in their own metal casings, so its not a neat resonator.  I also see self-oscillation outside of the case at a similar frequency though.

Regardless, I built two separate boxes and joined them by rigid coax cable and that solves the problem, whatever it originally was.